# Order of sphinx results is always ascending

Tags: php, search, sphinx

Somehow, whatever the query is, Sphinx always returns results in ascending order (ordered
by the primary ID). Say I'm searching for "foo" in these 5 documents:

1. `foo bar`
2. `foo foo foo foo`
3. `ja la la`
4. `foo foo foo foo foo`
5. `foo foo foo`

This would return matches: 1, 2, 4, 5 with 1 being the most relevant. At least, this is
what var_dump shows me in PHP. However, I want the real order to be: 4, 2, 5, 1. How am I
supposed to fix this? I'm using the following settings:

```
$sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$sphinx->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25);
$sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
```

The following source is being searched:

```
source pages
{
      type = mysql
      sql_query = SELECT text_id, book_id, content, page_number FROM text
      sql_attr_uint = page_number
      sql_attr_uint = book_id
      sql_query_pre = SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 4294967295
}
```

Comment: try `SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT` and also `SPH_RANK_SPH04`

Comment: That does not solve it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 match mode with SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT

Comment: This did the trick. I'm just wondering why SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT doesn't appear in the [Sphinx PHP API](http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs) nor on [php.net](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setrankingmode.php).

Comment: That page (http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs) is old. Its for 0.9.8 which is over 5 years old! The latest documentaiton is here: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html